# jquery filter: get the first match only?

Tags: jquery, css, filter, jquery-1.9

I want to find a match in the link's url and then do something about that link, such as changing it colour, etc.

```
$("a").filter("[href*='id=10']").css({color: 'red'});
```

html,

```
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=9&ajax=true">0</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=10&ajax=true">1</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=20&ajax=true">2</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=30&ajax=true">3</a>
<a href="http://website.come/folder/file.php?id=10&ajax=true">11</a>
```

But I have **two matches** in the links list and I just want the **first match**. What should I add to the jquery code?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9f3yx/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("a").filter("[href*='id=10']").first().css({color: 'red'});
```

And if you want, you can also do that :

```
$("a[href*='id=10']").first().css({color: 'red'});
```

Comment: Won't this get every single result and then return the first? Probably bad performance if you have a million things, but not a big deal with two.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("a").filter("[href*='id=10']:first").css({color: 'red'});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9f3yx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the psuedo class first:

```
$("a").filter("[href*='id=10']:first").css({color: 'red'});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("a").filter("[href*='id=10']:eq(0)").css({color: 'red'});`

`0` can be every `int` of course.

http://jsfiddle.net/ygFDM/